# Differences between "if in" and "if or if in"; looking for explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I get different results if I write **"if X or y in var"** than if I write **"if x in var or if y in var."**  Why is that?  I cannot find any documentation on this anywhere.

If, using the following Python3 code, I enter "rrrr" I get "whoohoo" not "WTF."  Only if I remove the code "elif "read" or "road" in choice:    print("whoohoo")," do I get "WTF."  Can anyone enlighten me on what I'm missing about the difference in the two?  As I say, I've searched broadly on the net and can't find anything on this.  I'm expecting them both to return the same thing but they do not.

```
var = "read", "road"
print(var)
print("what is your choice?")

choice = input("> ")

if "raed"  in choice or "raad" in choice:
    print('Not Good')

elif "read" or "road" in choice:
    print("whoohoo")

elif "read" in choice or "road" in choice:
    print("excellent")

else:
    print("WTF")
```

Comment: The first is equivalent to `if (x) or (y in var)`: it checks if `x` is a truthy value.

Answer (score 3):

This will check if `x` has a *truthy* value assigned to it (i.e. not empty), or else, if `var` contains the value for `y`

```
if x or y in var
```

This will check if `var` contains the value for `x`, or else, if `var` contains the value for `y`

```
if x in var or if y in var
```

Comment: @ShadowRanger updated